# How can I split a string in PHP at the nth occurrence of a needle?

Tags: php, string

There must be a fast and efficient way to split a (text) string at the "nth" occurrence of a needle, but I cannot find it. There is a fairly full set of functions in the [strpos comments in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#102336), but that seems a bit much for what I need.

I have plain text as `$string` and want to split it at *nth* occurrence of `$needle`, and in my case, `needle` is simply a space. (I can do the sanity checks!)

How can I do it?

Comment: What does "needle" mean in this context?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#102336 What you are looking for. Coming from the expression: [Searching for a needle in a haystack](https://www.languagecouncils.sg/goodenglish/resources/idioms/a-needle-in-a-haystack#:~:text=Meaning%3A,a%20needle%20in%20a%20haystack!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It could be:

```
function split2($string, $needle, $nth) {
    $max = strlen($string);
    $n = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
        if ($string[$i] == $needle) {
            $n++;
            if ($n >= $nth) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $arr[] = substr($string, 0, $i);
    $arr[] = substr($string, $i+1, $max);

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Only for $needle of one character size length

Answer (score 11):

Personally I'd just split it into an array with explode, and then implode the first `n-1` parts as the first half, and implode the remaining number as the second half.

Answer (score 10):

If your needle will always be one character, use [Galled's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956066/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-php-at-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-needle/5956183#5956183). It's going to be faster by quite a bit. If your $needle is a string, try this. It seems to work fine.

```
function splitn($string, $needle, $offset)
{
    $newString = $string;
    $totalPos = 0;
    $length = strlen($needle);
    for($i = 0; $i < $offset; $i++)
    {
        $pos = strpos($newString, $needle);

        // If you run out of string before you find all your needles
        if($pos === false)
            return false;
        $newString = substr($newString, $pos + $length);
        $totalPos += $pos + $length;
    }
    return array(substr($string, 0, $totalPos-$length), substr($string, $totalPos));
}
```

Comment: as you note, my situation entails a single-character "needle", but it's good to have this solution in the thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach that I would prefer over a regexp solution (see my other answer):

```
function split_nth($str, $delim, $n)
{
  return array_map(function($p) use ($delim) {
      return implode($delim, $p);
  }, array_chunk(explode($delim, $str), $n));
}
```

Just call it by:

```
split_nth("1 2 3 4 5 6", " ", 2);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1 2"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "3 4"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "5 6"
}
```

Comment: This solves a slightly different problem, of course -- not "split AT *nth* character" but "split at EVERY *nth* character. Not quite my scenario! Might be useful for someone else, though. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the answer to handle your point. But whether the edit is accepted or not I've combined it into a full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619720/4829915).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following:

```
/* Function copied from the PHP manual comment you referenced */
function strnripos_generic( $haystack, $needle, $nth, $offset, $insensitive, $reverse )
{
    //  If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.
    if(! is_string($needle)) {
        $needle = chr((int)$needle);
    }

    //  Are the supplied values valid / reasonable?
    $len = strlen($needle);
    if(1 > $nth || 0 === $len) {
        return false;
    }

    if($insensitive) {
        $haystack = strtolower($haystack);
        $needle   = strtolower($needle  );
    }

    if($reverse) {
        $haystack = strrev($haystack);
        $needle   = strrev($needle  );
    }

    //  $offset is incremented in the call to strpos, so make sure that the first
    //  call starts at the right position by initially decreasing $offset by $len.
    $offset -= $len;
    do
    {
        $offset = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset + $len);
    } while(--$nth && false !== $offset);

    return false === $offset || ! $reverse ? $offset : strlen($haystack) - $offset;
}

// Our split function
function mysplit ($haystack, $needle, $nth) {
    $position = strnripos_generic($haystack, $needle, $nth, 0, false, false);
    $retval = array();

    if ($position !== false) {
        $retval[0] = substr($haystack, 0, $position-1);
        $retval[1] = substr($haystack, $position);
        return $retval;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you just use the mysplit function, and you'll get an array with two substrings. First containing all characters up to the nth occurrence of the needle (not included), and second from the nth occurrence of the needle (included) to the end.

Comment: that certainly makes using these functions for splitting much more manageable. Galled's shorter solution works for me, but this could be useful for more complex situations than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but it seems to work:

```
$foo = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14';

$parts = preg_split('!([^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) !', $foo, -1,
            PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_dump($parts);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "1 2 3"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "4 5 6"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "7 8 9"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "10 11 12"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "13 14"
}
```

Replace the single spaces in the query with a single character you wish to split on. This expression won't work as-is with multiple characters as the delimiter.

This is hard coded for every third space. With a little tweaking, probably could be easily adjusted. Although a `str_repeat` to build a dynamic expression would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited [Galled's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956066/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-php-at-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-needle/5956183#5956183) to make it explode after every nth occurrences instead of just the first one.

```
function split2($string, $needle, $nth) {
  $max = strlen($string);
  $n = 0;
  $arr = array();

  //Loop trough each character
  for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {

    //if character == needle
    if ($string[$i] == $needle) {
      $n++;
      //Make a string for every n-th needle
      if ($n == $nth) {
        $arr[] = substr($string, $i-$nth, $i);
        $n=0; //reset n for next $nth
      }
      //Include last part of the string
      if(($i+$nth) >= $max) {
        $arr[] = substr($string, $i + 1, $max);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily, just do it:

```
$i = $pos = 0;
do {
    $pos = strpos($string, $needle, $pos+1);
} while(++$i < $nth);
```

Comment: Thanks to @Vardkin to find my bug! I fixed it.

Comment: `do ... while` begs the question whether there is a situation it does not handle. Is there?

Comment: [Vardkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956066/how-can-i-split-a-string-in-php-at-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-needle/57328977#57328977) claims this does not work. You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57239723/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar).

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Hamze GhaemPanah's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643380/hamze-ghaempanah) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956066/how-to-split-a-string-in-php-at-nth-occurrence-of-needle/57239723#57239723) for its brevity. However, there's a small bug in it.

In the original code:

```
$i = $pos = 0;
do {
    $pos = strpos($string, $needle, $pos+1);
} while( $i++ < $nth);
```

`$nth` in the `do while` loop should be replaced with `($nth-1)` as it will incorrectly iterate one extra time - setting the `$pos` to the position of the `$nth+1` instance of the needle. Here's an example [playground to demonstrate](https://www.tehplayground.com/vAutCoJvXvqRBWAu). If this link fails here is the code:

```
$nth = 2;
$string = "44 E conway ave west horse";
$needle = " ";

echo"======= ORIGINAL =======\n";

$i = $pos = 0;
do {
    $pos = strpos($string, $needle, $pos + 1);
} while( $i++ < $nth);

echo "position: $pos \n";
echo substr($string, 0, $pos) . "\n\n";

/*
    Outputs:

    ======= ORIGINAL =======
    position: 11
    44 E conway
*/

echo"======= FIXED =======\n";

$i = $pos = 0;
do {
    $pos = strpos($string, $needle, $pos + 1);
} while( $i++ < ($nth-1) );

echo "position: $pos \n";
echo substr($string, 0, $pos);

/*
    Outputs:

    ======= FIXED =======
    position: 4
    44 E

*/
```

That is, when searching for the position of the second instance of our needle, our loop iterates one extra time setting `$pos` to the position of our third instance of our needle. So, when we split the string on the second instance of our needle - as the OP asked - we get the incorrect substring.

Answer (score 1):

Taking [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956463/4829915) and adding a solution for [Dɑvïd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956066/how-to-split-a-string-in-php-at-nth-occurrence-of-needle/5956463#comment6869588_5956463):

```
function split_nth($str, $delim, $n) {
  $result = array_map(function($p) use ($delim) {
      return implode($delim, $p);
  }, array_chunk(explode($delim, $str), $n));
  $result_before_split = array_shift($result);
  $result_after_split = implode(" ", $result); 
  return array($result_before_split, $result_after_split);
}
```

Just call it by:

```
list($split_before, $split_after) = split_nth("1 2 3 4 5 6", " ", 2);
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pattern of zero or more non-delimiter characters followed by the delimiting character, reset the fullstring match before the delimiter, set the quantifier of the expression to the desired *n*.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wgutj))

```
$str = 'There must be a fast and efficient way to split a (text) string at the "nth" occurrence of a needle.';

var_export(
     preg_split('/([^ ]*\K ){2}/', $str)
);
```

To set a hard limit on the maximum number of elements generated, declare the 3rd parameter.  `2` will perform only one split and produce 2 elements.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/dvdc4)

Answer (score 0):

```
function strposnth($haystack,$needle,$n){
  $offset = 0;
  for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
    $indx = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
    if($i == $n || $indx === false)
        return $indx;
    else {
        $offset = $indx+1;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function split_nth($haystack, $needle, $nth){
    $result = array();
    if(substr_count($haystack,$needle) > ($nth-1)){
        $haystack = explode($needle, $haystack);
        $result[] = implode(array_splice($haystack, 0, $nth), $needle);
        $result[] = implode($haystack, $needle);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.