# Truncate string after certain number of occurrences of a substring

Tags: php, string, variables, substring, truncate

Let's say I have a string variable:

```
$string = "1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3";
```

I want to cut off the end of this string starting at the fourth occurrence of the substring "2", so `$string` is now equal to this:
`1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1`.

Effectively cutting off the fourth occurrence of "2" and everything after it.

How would one go about doing this? I know how to count the number of occurrences with `substr_count($string,"2");`, but I haven't found anything else searching online.

Comment: So far I can use substr_count to get the number of occurrences in a string

Comment: The number of occurrences is the wrong thing to concentrate on here, instead you should concentrate on the position of those occurrences (hint: use `strpos()`). So you should loop 4 times, and after the 4th loop take a substring up to the 4th occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = explode( "2", $string, 5 );
$string = array_slice( $string, 0, 4 );
$string = implode( "2", $string );
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GM795F

---

To add some confusion (as people are won't to do), you can turn this into a one-liner:

```
implode( "2", array_slice( explode( "2", $string, 5 ), 0, 4 ) );
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mgek8Z

---

For a more sane approach, drop it into a function:

```
function truncateByOccurence ($haystack, $needle,  $limit) {
    $haystack = explode( $needle, $haystack, $limit + 1 );
    $haystack = array_slice( $haystack, 0, $limit );
    return implode( $needle, $haystack );
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/76C9VE

Comment: It seems to work there, I'll have to test it out in my script

Comment: @MirkoAdari, I didn't know what implode and explode did when I posted this (a quick google search was all I needed to figure them out). This answer is a bit easier to understand, as it breaks up what has to be done into individual steps.

Comment: @MirkoAdari - When I started writing this answer you hadn't posted yet. After I finished writing it, supplied the demo  & posted, I realized that you had just given a similar answer. I figured this was much more complete, so I left it here.

Comment: @MirkoAdari - Also, you forgot to limit the `explode`.

Answer (score 2):

To find the position of the fourth `2` you could start with an offset of 0 and recursively call `$offset = strpos($str, '2', $offset) + 1` while keeping track of how many 2's you've matched so far. Once you reach 4, you just can just use `substr()`.

Of course, the above logic doesn't account for `false` returns or not enough 2's, I'll leave that to you.

---

You could also use `preg_match_all` with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to avoid doing the recursion yourself.

---

Another option, expanding on @matt idea:

```
implode('2', array_slice(explode('2', $string, 5), 0, -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this would work for you:

```
$str = "1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3"; // initial value
preg_match("#((.*)2){0,4}(.*)#",$str, $m);
//var_dump($m);
$str = $m[2]; // last value
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet should do it:

```
implode($needle, array_slice(explode($needle, $string), 0, $limit));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like

```
$newString = explode('2',$string);
```

and then loop through the array as many times as occurrences you need:

```
$finalString = null;
for($i=0:$i<2;$i++){
    $finalString .= 2 . $newString[$i];
}

echo $finalString;
```

Comment: Good idea, but you could eliminate the loop by using the `$limit` argument in `explode`.

Answer (score 0):

Match zero or more non-2 characters followed by a 2 -- repeated 4 times.

Restart the fullstring match before every matched 2 with `\K`.

After successfully matching four 2's, match the remaining characters and replace the matched characters with an empty string.

```
$string = "1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3";

echo preg_replace(
         '~([^2]*\K2){4}.*~',
         '',
         $string
     );
```

I have similar pattern advice at [this answer which splits a string on every n characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76192679/2943403).